# Smart select from MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, unique

I am not great with MySQL, so I'd need your help.

I have table with columns

> logId, playerId, playerName, updateTime

**logId** is primary and is auto-increment.
**playerId** is int(11)
**playerName** is varChar(36)
**updateTime** is int as well (storing unix timestamp when the entry is made)

I have these entries in the database:

> 1, 444, John, 1379434514
>
> 2, 444, John, 1379434414
>
> 3, 445, Mike, 1379434410
>
> 4, 444, John, 1379434614

I would like to fetch only one for each unique playerId, with the greatest integer in "updateTime" column (in this example it's the one with logId of 4 for playerId of 444).

Is there any way I can group all the entries for specific playerId, then just select one of those (the newest one)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be obtained by joining your table with a subquery that selects the identifying (maximal) `updateTime` for each group:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT playerId, MAX(updateTime) updateTime FROM my_table GROUP BY playerId
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10faa/1/0).

Note that you really ought to use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) type for `updateTime`; and furthermore I suspect that `playerName` may violate [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!
Why using MySQL's TIMESTAMP for updateTime? What's wrong with using time() in PHP?

Comment: Also what's with that "t" at the end of the query?

Comment: @ToniPerić: `t` is the alias given to the table that is materialised from the subquery; it could be anything that you want.

Comment: @ToniPerić: And it's better to use `TIMESTAMP` so that you can perform date/time operations natively in MySQL without needing to first convert; also MySQL will handle conversion to/from your session timezone for you; and MySQL can be configured to automatically set/update the value for you when the record is created/modified, if so desired.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can simply write:

```
select max(updateTime) 
from t1 
group by playerId
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a127b/1)

Comment: I think the OP also wants the other corresponding fields, such as the `logId`?

Comment: But that brings back only the updateTime column, I need them all (*) where the updateTime is the greatest number for a group of one playerId